# What is the synonym of the word "thesaurus"?

Tags: synonyms

If the meaning of the word **thesaurus** is

> a book containing set or collection of synonyms grouped according to
>   their meaning.

Then, what shall be the synonym of the word "**thesaurus**"?

Comment: Not every word has a synonym.

Comment: Have you tried looking it up in a [thesaurus](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/thesaurus)? Also, I'm not sure I follow your reasoning – how does the definition of the word *thesaurus* beg the question "What is the synonym of the word *thesaurus*?"?

Comment: @eques you are right as I did not  find it in Google so I have asked here .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the thesaurus, I found synonyms.

> **Reference book**-a book containing useful facts or specially organized information, as an encyclopedia, dictionary, atlas, yearbook, etc.
>
> **Onomasticon**- a collection or listing of words especially in a specialized field (as science or commerce)
>
> **Lexicon**-a wordbook or dictionary, especially of Greek, Latin, or Hebrew.
>
> **Language Reference Book**

Source:http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/thesaurus?s=t

I'm not sure if this question was just supposed to be ironic, or serious. But, this is a serious answer.